# conditional formatting in Excel to highlight important dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet with hundred of dates. Is there anyway to conditional format those cells to highlight dates that are fast approaching in red, and dates far in the future in green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Excel?  In Excel 2010 (and I presume 2007) you can use a Graded Color Scale starting at Red and changing to Green for your range of dates.  In fact a Red-Yellow-Green scale is one of the options under the "Conditional Formatting" ribbon item.

To set conditional formatting using VBA use a macro like this:

```
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
    xlConditionValueLowestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
    .Color = 8109667
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
    xlConditionValuePercentile
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
    .Color = 8711167
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
    xlConditionValueHighestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
    .Color = 7039480
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: i'm using 2010, i see it, it works great, is there anyway to see the vba coding for this? i like to change the dates to present day everytime i open the excel

Comment: It doesn't use VBA - it's buillt-in Excel.  To _replicate_ it you could use a macro like this:

Answer (score 2):

You don't need VBA to do this. In my opinion, VBA will unnecessarily complicate things in this particular case. (This coming from a VBA enthusiast of sorts.)

[image]

This is Excel 2003, but the idea is the same in 2010.

Comment: Why was this down voted? Damn I hate when people don't leave comments! +1 on the use of Conditional formatting. I believe it is a case of retaliation. You get 2 unexplained downvotes (separate threads) within a minute!

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Thanks for your support! Yeah, I'm thinking retaliation as well. Some people have too much time on their hands.

Comment: Upvoted to cancel out another down vote and because it's a great answer.